# AppMobi fails json parsing on iOS

Tags: ios, appmobi

I am developing a mobile app with the AppMobi tools and xdk.  If I make a call to (accepts POST only)    `http://mg.smartmax.com/sightmaxwebservices/sightmaxwebservice.svc/jsoperator/TestjqMobi`

The returned json fails parsing on iOS only (android works fine).  This same call works fine in mobile safari, but it seems when its called from the app, it takes a different path and errors.  This seems to be a [known issue](http://forums.appmobi.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=2948&sid=5fe718398d57af07a376910f620f64b7) and was wondering if anyone had a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I work at appMobi - this appears to be a bug with the native container in iOS.  Have you tried building your app and testing (app*lab doesn't have the latest code base).

Comment: No, ive only used the app*lab to test.  Is this something that you think has been fixed with them?

Comment: Could be - like I said we make fixes to the containers alot in between app*lab updates.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to parse the JSON?  Something like

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

As a workaround for now I suppose you could just include and use another parser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your server is properly encoding the JSON.

I ran into this exact same issue.  If you are using Drupal as your backend, use their function drupal_json_encode instead of PHP's json_encode.  The information I was passing to the app was generated by a WYSYWIG editor, and perhaps that is what drupal's json encoding function takes into account that php's json encoding doesn't.